# Build a re-usable list of paths from ansible copy module

Tags: ansible

Given the following ansible snippet:

```
- name: copy artifact
  copy: src=target/{{ item.artifactId }}-{{ item.version }}.{{ item.type }} dest={{ item.dest }}
  become: yes
  with_items: "{{ gavdeploy_list }}"
  register: artifact

TASK: [gavdeploy | debug msg="{{ artifact }}"] ********************************
ok: [mymachine] => {
        "msg": "{'msg': 'All items completed', 'changed': False, 
'results': [{'group': 'wildfly', 'uid': 11002, 'dest': 
'/opt/wildfly/standalone/deployments/foolistener-1.0.104.war', 
'checksum': '4c110c4833cf37535b37325ef01a4212ed4a14c4', 'changed': False, 
'owner': 'wildfly', 'item': {'endpoint': 'http://localhost:8080/foo-
listener-bot/health', 'group': 'wildfly', 'dest': 
'/opt/wildfly/standalone/deployments', 'version': u'1.0.104', 'owner': 
'wildfly', 'type': 'war', 'groupId': 'company.foo.listener', 
'artifactId': 'foolistener'}, 'state': 'file', 'gid': 11002, 'secontext': 
'system_u:object_r:usr_t:s0', 'mode': '0644', 'invocation': 
{'module_name': u'copy', 'module_complex_args': {}, 'module_args': 
u'src=target/foolistener-1.0.104.war 
dest=/opt/wildfly/standalone/deployments owner=wildfly group=wildfly 
mode=644'}, 'path': '/opt/wildfly/standalone/deployments/foolistener-
1.0.104.war', 'size': 38665931},
```

I can see in the -vv output that we have output

```
'path': '/opt/wildfly/standalone/deployments/foolistener-
    1.0.104.war'
'changed': False
```

I would be grateful if someone could show me a way to extract path and changed fields, in such a way I can re-use this with jboss-cli to perform a hot deploy.

E.g. ( but I am in deep waters here )

```
- name: hot deploy
  shell: /path/to/jboss-cli.sh --command "deploy {{ item.path }}"
  with_items: "{{ artefact }}"
```

If I can get the basics of this working, I can probably figure out how to deal with changed: False or True myself.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solution your problem:

```
- name: hot deploy
  shell: "/path/to/jboss-cli.sh --command deploy {{ item.item.path }}"
  with_items: "{{ artefact.results }}"
```

Hope that help you.